# Replication of information across multiple pages

Tags: pages

I'm trying to redo my companies SharePoint online. I'm not sure how to word it so I'll give an example:

I have a page with a name and phone number on it: ie Bob Smith 555-5555.

I want to embed or show that name and number on multiple different pages. Also if I were to change the initial page, like Bob got a new number, I change it on the initial page and it changes on all other pages. If you know Confluence, I would like something along the lines of the include page macro.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure about the details for the requirement but first thing that comes to my mind is to create a SharePoint list with 2 columns, name and phome number. Add 1 item with name and phone number. Then create a page, add this list to that page, then save the page as a template. When you create more pages out of this page they will all have the same list inside and you can just change the list now and it will change across all pages. You can also add more info to the list using this way to store more names and phones.